# How to migrate airflow variables between DEV and PROD environments?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

We are using airflow to schedule our data pipelines, as part of it we also have added few connections and variables in airflow admin.

Everything worked fine in DEV, now we want to setup PROD environment. How do we migrate these values into PROD environment.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55626195/export-all-airflow-connections-to-new-environment)

Answer (score 3):

You can list or export variables and connection through the command line: https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html

Relevant commands:

- airflow variables -e variables.json
- airflow connections --list

Comment: Yes I found those commands , where export work only for variables but not for connections.

Answer (score 0):

Variables, I generally have JSON files in our code repo to store non sensitive variables for different environments, which can then be imported via the command line easily and changes are tracked through git.

For connections the other option which is possible is to use environment variables instead of setting up in the UI, you can set connection properties using `AIRFLOW_CONN_{CONNECTION_NAME}` for example `AIRFLOW_CONN_AWS_DEFAULT` for connection `aws_default`

The value stored in the variable must be in a URI format i.e. `postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/master` or `s3://accesskey:secretkey@S3`