# Export all airflow connections to new environment

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to migrate all the existing airflow connections to a new airflow.

I was looking at the cli options `airflow connections --help`, it gives an option to list but doesn't give an option to export/import to/from json format.

Is there a way via cli/airflow ui to migrate connections across multiple airflows?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can either connect directly to the Airflow meta db and dump those connections, then load them in a separate database.
However, if you want to automate something like this, you can get started by dumping them in a CSV file:

```py
from airflow.utils import db
from airflow.models import Connection
import csv

outfile = open('myconnections.csv', 'w')
outcsv = csv.writer(outfile)

with db.create_session() as session:
    connections = session.query(Connection).all()

conn_list = [
    [getattr(c, column.name) for column in Connection.__mapper__.columns]
    for c in connections
]
outcsv.writerows(conn_list)
outfile.close()
```

After that, you can load that to a new DB manually or with a similar script.

**IMPORTANT**: if you have enabled encryption, the passwords stored for these connections will be encrypted, and when you load them to the new DB, you must use the identical fernet key, or otherwise you won't be able to decrypt them.

Answer (score 12):

This will allow you to export all connections so that they could be re-added elsewhere via the CLI (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/index.html#creating-a-connection-from-the-cli). Run it in Python wherever your existing installation is:

```
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook

for c in ['my', 'list', 'of', 'connections']:
    conn = BaseHook.get_connection(c)
    print("airflow connections --add \\ \n \
    --conn_id '{conn_id}' \\ \n \
    --conn_type '{conn_type}' \\ \n \
    --conn_host '{conn_host}' \\ \n \
    --conn_schema '{conn_schema}' \\ \n \
    --conn_login '{conn_login}' \\ \n \
    --conn_password '{conn_password}' \\ \n \
    --conn_port '{conn_port}' \\ \n \
    --conn_extra '{conn_extra}' \\".format(
        conn_id=conn.conn_id,
        conn_type=conn.conn_type,
        conn_host=conn.host,
        conn_schema=conn.schema,
        conn_login=conn.login,
        conn_password=conn.password,
        conn_port=conn.port,
        conn_extra=conn.extra,
    ))
```

This also outputs the decrypted password. Tested and working on Airflow 1.10.12.

Comment: Wow this litterally output all the connection output into CLI ready commands, Thanks alot !

Answer (score 4):

I wrote quick Python script that generates a `connection-commands.sh` file with ALL the connections in one airflow environemnt, that can be run in a second airflow environemnt to import the connections.

```py
from airflow.models import Connection
from airflow.utils.db import create_session

with create_session() as session:
    connections = session.query(Connection).order_by(Connection.conn_id).all()

connection_commands = []

conn: Connection
for conn in connections:
    conn_command_lines = [
        f"airflow connections",
        f"--add",
        f"--conn_id='{conn.conn_id}'",
        f"--conn_type='{conn.conn_type}'",
    ]

    # add `host`, if non-empty
    if conn.host:
        conn_command_lines.append(f"--conn_host='{conn.host}'")

    # add `port`, if non-empty
    if conn.port:
        conn_command_lines.append(f"--conn_port='{conn.port}'")

    # add `schema`, if non-empty
    if conn.schema:
        conn_command_lines.append(f"--conn_schema='{conn.schema}'")

    # add `login`, if non-empty
    if conn.login:
        conn_command_lines.append(f"--conn_login='{conn.login}'")

    # add `password`, if non-empty
    if conn.password:
        conn_command_lines.append(f"--conn_password='{conn.password}'")

    # add `extra`, if non-empty
    if conn.extra:
        conn_command_lines.append(f"--conn_extra='{conn.extra}'")

    # combine the command lines
    conn_command = " \\\n    ".join(conn_command_lines) + ";"

    connection_commands.append(conn_command)


with open("connection-commands.sh", mode="w") as f:
    f.write("#!/usr/bin/env bash")
    f.write("\n\n")
    for conn_command in connection_commands:
        f.write(conn_command)
        f.write("\n\n")
```

### Output Format

The format of the generated `connection-commands.sh` file is as follows:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

airflow connections \
    --add \
    --conn_id='my_connection_1' \
    --conn_type='http' \
    --conn_host='https://example.com' \
    --conn_login='user' \
    --conn_password='password';

airflow connections \
    --add \
    --conn_id='my_connection_2' \
    --conn_type='http' \
    --conn_host='https://example.com' \
    --conn_login='user' \
    --conn_password='password';

...
```

**WARNING:** the `airflow connections --add ...` command will only add a connection if the connection does not already exist, you will need to delete the connection first if you want to "update" it.

Answer (score 1):

For those using astronomer.io, this DAG will output YAML suitable for pasting into `airflow_settings.yaml`, which will then imported at next start:

https://gist.github.com/vshih/c486bef62d072f13ba21e327f094ec6f

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add that connections can also be easily exported in the URL format using the `get_uri()` function, like this:

```
outfile = open('conns.csv', 'w')
outcsv = csv.writer(outfile)

with db.create_session() as session:
    connections = session.query(Connection).all()

conn_list = []
for c in connections:
    if 'default' not in c.conn_id:
        conn_list.append([c.conn_id, c.get_uri()])

outcsv.writerows(conn_list)
outfile.close()
```